# AWS Appsync $ctx vs $context in resolvers

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync, appsync-apollo-client, aws-appsync-ios

I understand that context is what ever name you define in your Lambda functions but when it comes to Appsync resolvers I'm a bit confused. I've seen both `$ctx` and `$context` being used in AppSync resolvers including in AWS docs. Some of AWS's own code generation tools like AWS Amplify CLI create resolvers that use both in the same code! I can't find anything in the docs explaining this. What's going on here?

Comment: I'm in the process of scrubbing our docs and replacing `$context` with `$ctx` for consistency. I'll add a note to the [Resolver Mapping page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html) explaining that `$ctx` is an alias. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*(AWS AppSync dev here)*

`$ctx` and `$context` in AWS AppSync refer to the same [Resolver Context](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html). We added `$ctx` as an alias for `$context` to reduce the number of characters users have to type (`$ctx` is 50% shorter than `$context`!!)

Choosing `$context` or `$ctx` is a personal preference. I prefer `$ctx` when I'm authoring AWS AppSync resolvers.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Does the same apply to arguments? I've seen some place use $ctx.args... ?Any other helpful aliases?

Comment: $ctx.* and $context.* refer to the same thing.

Comment: Just a minor note, $ctx is not allowed when referencing cache keys. Caching keys need to start with $context.args, $context.arguments, $context.identity, or $context.source, otherwise AppSync fails with 400

Comment: Why not `$c`? 85% less to type.